# Java Statements execute except for changing of variable

Tags: java, variables, nested

So the premise here is that a String array of five "cards" is checked to see what sort of hand is given. The type of hand is an int where the higher number is a better hand. This particular segement of code was not written by me, but by a friend who is having trouble and I can't quite find the problem

```
int checkHand(String[][] Hand) {
    boolean check = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(!Hand[i][1].equals(Hand[i+1][1]))
            check = false;
    }

    //check pair starts
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(int n = i + 1; n < 5; n++) {

            if(Hand[i][0].equals(Hand[n][0])) {
                BestCard = 1;//###OUTPUTS 1 FOR A PAIR###
                temp = Hand[0];
                Hand[0] = Hand[i];
                Hand[i] = temp;
                temp = Hand[1];
                Hand[1] = Hand[n];
                Hand[n] = temp;
                //check three of a kind starts 
                for(int p = n + 1; p < 5; p++) {
                    if(Hand[i][0].equals(Hand[p][0])) {
                        temp = Hand[2];
                        Hand[2] = Hand[p];
                        Hand[p] = temp;
                        BestCard = 3; //Problem starts here- Output 3 for Three of a Kind

                        if(Hand[3][0].equals(Hand[4][0]))
                            BestCard = 6;//###OUTPUTS A 6 FOR A FULL HOUSE###
                        else if(Hand[2][0].equals(Hand[3][0])) {
                            BestCard = 7;
                        }
                        else if(Hand[2][0].equals(Hand[4][0])) {
                            temp = Hand[3];
                            Hand[3] = Hand[4];
                            Hand[4] = temp;
                            BestCard = 7;//###OUTPUTS A 7 FOR A FOUR OF A KIND###
                        }
                    } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(check && BestCard<4)
        BestCard = 5;//###OUTPUTS 5 FOR A FLUSH###
    else if(check && BestCard == 4)
        BestCard = 8;//###OUTPUTS 8 FOR A STRAIGHT FLUSH###

    return BestCard;
}
```

When this runs (and there's more to it, but this is what I believe to be the problem area,) It can determine whether or not said hand is a pair or flush. Aside from that, it does not return the proper number. The strange thing is that everything else in the statement will run- if there is a three of a kind forced but not ordered, the hand will be reordered to be proper. The same occurs with a four of a kind. Comments are given where the value of BestCard is changed. int BestCard and String[] temp are already initialized.

Answer (score 0):

well I found your error.
Lets say your hand is 3 2 K 3 Q

your i = 0 so n = 1 and p = 2
for the initial loop through nothing really happens,
so p goes through
 and on the second go through, when p = 2. you hit a problem
the first line is
if(hand i == hand p) 
at this point hand i = 3 AND hand p = 3
BUT you do not have 3 of a kind you simply have a pair.
Also the program is going to give this error again once the p for loop finishes and n=2 because then p will again start at 3 and return that you have 3 of a kind, when you really only have a pair.

I hope this helps.

I would suggest making each of them their own for loops instead of trying to do them all at once, a lot less confusing, and easier to do when you are newer to java.

PS you should probably change your bestcard values so you can win by high card if no one has a pair.